# I am trying to recieve text in any language from JSP and save it into the data base

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to recieve text in any language from JSP and save it into the data base. While I am debugging I can see that the text has been recieved in the servlet but when I am printing the same variable I get ?????.  I tried to save the text in a static variable and tried to print it.
String a="नमस्ते";
System.out.print(a).

When I did this inside the doPost method I get ???? in the console.
But in the same servlet if I write a main method and do it I am getting the expected output.
I have set my request and response type to UTF-8.

Here is my code

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      try {

        String feedBack = null, prob = null;
        String a = "नमस्ते";
        System.out.println(a);
        feedBack = request.getParameter("feedback");
        System.out.println("Feedback is " + feedBack);
        System.out.println("Feedback is " + a);
        LogOut.log.error("In FeedbackServlet " + e);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "नमस्ते";
             System.out.println(a);
}
```

In the main function I am getting the hindi letters on the console and when the doPost is executed I am getting ???? in the console for the variable a.

Comment: Are you sure your console is UTF8-enabled?

Comment: Can you provide the JSP code and all the directives you used in the JSP

Comment: Yes my console is UTF-8 enabled. I have tried printing hindi on it and it worked.

Comment: @Rohan I am not having problem with my JSPs as I while debugging I can see that the actual hindi text has been recieved.

Answer (score 0):

I have attach some code, can you add the connection coding java file then insert the Hindi or tamil word to db.It will insert.

Connection jave File code as below

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "username", "password");
```

Getting parameter from jsp like controller or helper class as below

```
String stateName = new String(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getParameter("stateName").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

display jsp First line add code as below

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Let me know if any error add in comments

Comment: I think you got my problem wrong. I am having problem with conversion of the data when my Servlet recieves it not while saving it in DB as I had tried with static data and it worked. Anyways thanks for your solution I have already implemented it.